# Is there any way for uploading files to 2 or more servers at same time using PHP & forms?

Tags: php, html, upload

I'm just wondering is that even possible using forms and PHP? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A single form can only be submitted to one location.
However, the PHP script could then upload it to another location.

Comment: That's exact what I asked. Thanks ThiefMaster.

Answer (score 1):

Forms can't be submitted to more locations than one, but is you absolutely need to do that, you could create an AJAX uploader to handle it.

Comment: Yes, I know for AJAX uploader, but I just wanted to do it using PHP and forms only... no other scripts. Thanks.